# pandas best way to construct dataframe from multiple lists of column names

Tags: python, pandas

```
l1 = dfx.v1.unique()
l2 = dfx.v2.unique()
day_parts = [1,2,3,4]
week_days = list(calendar.day_name)
df = pd.DataFrame() # what goes here?

l1[0] | l1[1] | ... | l2[0] | l2[1] | ... | day_parts[0] | day_parts[1] | .....
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 v     a       c      x       s      ...    2               1            .....
 v     a       c      x       s      ...    2               1            .....
 v     a       c      x       s      ...    2               1            .....
 v     a       c      x       s      ...    2               1            .....
 v     a       c      x       s      ...    2               1            .....
```

what is the best way to construct a data frame from multiple lists of column names? of course one could append all lists, but I was wondering if there is a better more pythonic-pandas way to achieve it?

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

```
L = [l1, l2, day_parts,  week_days]

import itertools

cols = list(itertools.chain(*L))

cols = [item for sublist in L for item in sublist]

cols = sum(L, [])

cols = l1 + l2 + day_parts + week_days
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
```

Comment: I'm afraid you miss understood, the lists are column names not values of columns

Comment: l1 = [1,2,3,4]
l2 = list(calendar.day_name)
L = l1 + l2 
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=L)

actually that is enough :)

Comment: so it is just appending, no special constructors pandas provide, thanks!

Comment: @mkmostafa - Super, so first solution was enough :) Nice day!